# Tomcat redirects to wrong url after logging in

Tags: java, eclipse, authentication, tomcat, redirect

I'm having this problem with my web application, where I'm performing form based authentication through Tomcat and it redirects me to a logo image file instead of redirecting to the index.html file which contains that logo image...

I'm going to:

```
http://localhost:8080/GenTreeUploader/Servlet
```

Then it gives me the login form and after logging in successfully, I'm not in that url I was going to, but I get redirected to:

```
http://localhost:8080/GenTreeUploader/images/gdia_logo.png
```

After I'm authenticated when I go to:

```
http://localhost:8080/GenTreeUploader/Servlet
```

I then get redirected tot he correct place and not the image file.

I'm attaching my web.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <!-- WELCOME FILE LIST -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/Servlet</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- Security -->

    <security-constraint>

        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Wildcard means whole app requires authentication</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>

        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>tomcat</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>

        <user-data-constraint>
            <!-- transport-guarantee can be CONFIDENTIAL, INTEGRAL, or NONE -->
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/error.html</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

     <!-- Main Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>GenTreeUploaderServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.ktu.gdia.presentation.web.GenTreeUploader</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>GenTreeUploaderServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Servlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            60
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Well? Any ideas why it doesn't work as expected? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like the problem is in your Servlet code or somewhere else that you haven't provided to analyse and help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The redirects were actually happening, because those resources that were requested in the login file were actually protected, because I had selected the whole path as a secure resource:

```
<web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Wildcard means whole app requires authentication</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
```

So I created a new folder called "Admin" and moved my files that needed to be secured there, as well as modified the path for the servlet. Here's how my current (fixed) web.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <!-- WELCOME FILE LIST -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Admin/Servlet</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- Security -->

    <security-constraint>

        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Wildcard means whole app requires authentication</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/Admin/*</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>

        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>

        <user-data-constraint>
            <!-- transport-guarantee can be CONFIDENTIAL, INTEGRAL, or NONE -->
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/error.html</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

     <!-- Main Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>GenTreeUploaderServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.ktu.gdia.presentation.web.GenTreeUploader</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>GenTreeUploaderServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Admin/Servlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            60
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

So now Tomcat wouldn't redirect me to the image or css files after logging in anymore, because they now became acessible to anyone without authentication.

Comment: Strange, if I use the <transport-guarantee>Confidential</transport-guarantee> it doesnt work