# How to get Images and CSS shown in login/error files for Tomcat authentication

Tags: java, css, authentication, tomcat

I have Tomcat authentication for my web app and my problem is that the login.jsp and error.html files used as login and error forms don't seem to support styling or images. I've tried getting the path of the files and they're showing that they're in the correct path, so I don't get it why they dont' support images or CSS? Any ideas how to enable css for this?

Edit:

Well I tested in the following manner, if I try to access a secure path and will get redirected to login.jsp which is in

```
D:\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp7\wtpwebapps\GenTreeUploader\
```

In the same directory where the login.jsp is there is index.html. and if I access it directly it also opens and it shows that it's in the same directory as for the login.jsp. Now the differences are that for index.html css and images work and for login.jsp they don't, the files have basically the same templates for styles. The directory is the same as Web Content as shown in the pic below:

[image]

My login.jsp has this code in it:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <HEAD>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <TITLE>GenTreeFromWord (GDIA) </TITLE>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>

        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container"> <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </a> <a class="brand" href="#"><img src="images/gdia_logo.png" width="111" height="30" alt="GDIA logo" /></a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li><a href="/GenTreeUploader/Servlet?action=backToGmis">Go back to GMIS</a></li>
                            <li class="active"><a href="/GenTreeUploader/Servlet?action=home">GenTreeFromWord (GDIA)</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/GenTreeUploader/Servlet?action=contact">Contact</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/GenTreeUploader/Servlet?action=about">About</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.nav-collapse --> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span1">


                </div>

                <div class="span10">                   
                    <!-- Old page body with scriptlets -->
                    <h1> 
                        <center>Welcome to GDIA<center>

                        <% System.out.println(request.getRealPath("/")); %>

                        <%

                        String url = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURL().toString();
                        String queryString = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getQueryString();

                        System.out.println(url + "?" + queryString);

                        %>

                    </h1>

                    <p> 

                    <!--  login body start -->
                    <div class="span4"></div>




                    <div class="row-fluid container span4">

                        <form class="form-signin" name="credentials" action="j_security_check" method="post">
                            <h4 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h4>
                              <input type="text" name="j_username" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Username" tabindex="1">
                                <input type="password" name="j_password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" tabindex="2">
                            <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login" tabindex="3">Sign in</button>

                             <br><br>
                        </form>

                    </div>

                    <div class="span4"></div>
                        <!-- login body end -->


                    </p>
                    <!-- Body ends here -->
                </div>

                <div class="span1">


                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I don't see how it's possible to disable the CSS for a file like error.html, most probably this is a directory issue. Can you post the code of the error.html and your directory structure above?

Comment: are your image and css files in a secured path, that's not accessible until after login?

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek No they're not. They used to be, but I changed the secure path, because I thought maybe these resources weren't accessible until I was authenticated, however now I secured not everything, but just a folder (Everything under Admin)

Comment: @user2019515 Yeah, I'm wondering also how that is possible, because if I access the index file directly, the css works, but if Tomcat loads login/error files the styles don't work anymore. How can I find out what's causing this? I've edited my code.

Comment: Just as a test, try removing all security, and then hit the logon page. If it works, then its a security problem. If it doesn't, then its a path problem. I'd also try a standalone version of tomcat instead of the IDE plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem is the same as for the problem in here:
[Tomcat redirects to wrong url after logging in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660260/tomcat-redirects-to-wrong-url-after-logging-in)

Additional details would be, that by testing previously, the paths were messed up, so I changed them to absolute paths, I found this out by inspecting the source code of the login.jsp file... Thanks to everybody helping to formulate this answer.